# std::map<CString, int> insert CString and have a count of each

Tags: c++

I want to have a map of `CString`s and count them in mapped pair.

For example if I have:

```
"Banana",
"Banana",
"Apple",
"Apple",
"Pear"
```

I want to have `("Banana", 2), ("Apple", 2), ("Pear", 1)`.

```
int sortFruit (std::map<CString, int> &mapFruitTypes)
{
   for (const auto& a : someArray)
        {
            CString fruitType = a -> GetFruitType();

            int i = 0;

            mapFruitTypes.emplace(fruitType , i++);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Is this correct way to do it? Or should I use something else (instead of `emplace` ?)

Comment: `fruitType` is meant to be `fruitType`? So `mapFruitTypes[fruitType]++;` should be enough for your purpose. Given that you don't sorted order, you may also consider `unordered_map`.

Comment: You mean like `mapFruitTypes.emplace(csType, mapFruitTypes[csType]++);` ?

Comment: @usr, for `unordered_map` one will have to provide a hash function, whereas `operator<` needed for `map` is already there.

Comment: No. Just `mapFruitTypes[fruitType]++;`. No need for `i` or use of `emplace` at all.

Comment: @Evg May be. That depends on `CString` is. It may be needed even for `std::map` actually.

Comment: I've fixed my question. Actually it is quite complex and would require a lot of code. But it is similar to fruit example. I have to count some strings from some array and put them in `std::map<CString, int>` ... This map (`mapFruitTypes`) is initially empty and has to be filled. I thought I need to use `insert` or `emplace` for that. That's why I am confused with `mapFruitTypes[fruitType]++;`

Comment: @harunB10 `operator []` for a map inserts a new item if the key doesn't exist in the map, and the value for the new key is default initialized (which means that the value will start at 0 for `int`).  Then regardless of whether the key existed or not, `++` is done on the value associated with the key, thus the value is incremented by 1.  That's how the whole thing works.

Comment: Ok guys. It's much clear now. @usr thanks a lot. Sorry I cannot upvote and approve because you replied in comment.

Comment: @harunB10 -- You could also have done this: `mapFruitTypes.insert({fruitType, 0}).first->second++;`.  This basically does the same thing as `[]` I described, where the return value of `insert` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply increment the map's value for each fruit type as you see them. When accessing map's value with [operator `[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), it gets inserted and also the value is value-initialized for type (so the value gets `0` - for `int` type).

So this is sufficient (for both inserting new key(s) & counting them):

```
   for (const auto& a : someArray)
   {
            CString fruitType = a -> GetFruitType();
            mapFruitTypes[fruitType]++;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three ways to map the key to the current count of the key.

**Method 1:**

Use the `std::map::operator[]`:

```
int sortFruit (std::map<CString, int> &mapFruitTypes)
{
   for (const auto& a : someArray)
       mapFruitTypes[a->GetFruitType()]++;
   return 0;
}
```

---

**Method 2:**

Use the [std::map::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) method, and take advantage of the return value (which is a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`), where the `iterator` is the iterator to the inserted item, or the existing item if the key already exists.

```
int sortFruit (std::map<CString, int> &mapFruitTypes)
{
   for (const auto& a : someArray)
       mapFruitTypes.insert({a->GetFruitType(), 0}).first->second++;
   return 0;
}
```

---

**Method 3:**

Use the [std::map::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) method, and take advantage of the return value, similar to Method 2:

```
int sortFruit (std::map<CString, int> &mapFruitTypes)
{
   for (const auto& a : someArray)
       mapFruitTypes.emplace(a->GetFruitType(), 0).first->second++;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Very helpful explanation!

Comment: I added the other two methods, since in my experience, you don't see a lot of C++ programmer who use `std::map` (or unordered_map) utilize the return value of `insert` or `emplace` too often.  Utilizing `insert` or `emplace` in this fashion cuts down on the  boilerplate "search for item -- if item doesn't exist insert it and do this, if it does exist, do the same thing".  This basically mimics `[ ]`, but with the added information on whether an item existed (the `bool` in the returned `std::pair`)..